# Laravel querying many to many records with eager loading conditions

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

So my app has structure like so.

- **payments** hasAndBelongsToMany **payers**
- **payers** belongsTo **users** (**users** hasMany **payers**)

I want to query all the payments (and the pivot data) for a certain user ID. I have been using this query that returns all the payments, regardless of user_id:

```
$payment_data = Payment::with('payers')->get();
```

Now, if I want to only get payments whose payers have a user_id of, say, 5 I tried this:

```
$payment_data = Payment::with(array(
        'payers' => function($q){
           $q->where('user_id', '=', 5);
        }))->get();
```

But it returns almost the same result except the condition only applies to the **payers**, not the payments i.e. I still get all payments in the payments table, just not the pivot data if the `user_id` condition is not fulfilled. I can technically just use this result and filter out the ones where the `payers` sub-array is empty but this would become very inefficient with large numbers of payments.

What's the correct way to form this query?

#### Edit

Here is a basic representation of my db structure:

[image]

And the plain SQL query would be something like this (RDMS varies but you get the idea):

```
SELECT payments.*, payers_payments.* 
FROM   payments 
       RIGHT JOIN (payers 
                   LEFT JOIN payers_payments 
                          ON payers.id = payers_payments.payer_id) 
               ON payments.id = payers_payments.payment_id 
WHERE  payers.user_id = 5;
```

Using `wherehas` gives this result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   "payments" 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   "payers" 
               INNER JOIN "payer_payment" 
                       ON "payers"."id" = "payer_payment"."payer_id" 
        WHERE  "payer_payment"."payment_id" = "payments"."id" 
               AND "payers"."user_id" = '1') >= '1'
```

Which is not what I want.

#### Edit 2

OK so after much fiddling I know that I need to use eager loading as I need the pivot fields as well as the fields from the payment model itself. Here's an example showing 3 payments and their pivot data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [payment_date] => 2014-03-07
            [company] => Franco Manca
            [item] => Pizza
            [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:08
            [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:08
            [payers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => tim
                            [email] => tim@tim.com
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:07:23
                            [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:07:23
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [payment_id] => 2
                                    [payer_id] => 1
                                    [amount] => 21.0
                                    [pays] => 0
                                    [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:08
                                    [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:27:45
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => tom
                            [email] => tom@tom.com
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:35
                            [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:35
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [payment_id] => 2
                                    [payer_id] => 2
                                    [amount] => 0.0
                                    [pays] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:27:45
                                    [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:27:45
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [payment_date] => 2014-03-05
            [company] => Kaff
            [item] => Cocktail
            [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:17:05
            [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:17:05
            [payers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => tim
                            [email] => tim@tim.com
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:07:23
                            [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:07:23
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [payment_id] => 3
                                    [payer_id] => 1
                                    [amount] => 12.0
                                    [pays] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:17:05
                                    [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:17:05
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => tom
                            [email] => tom@tom.com
                            [user_id] => 1
                            [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:35
                            [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:16:35
                            [pivot] => Array
                                (
                                    [payment_id] => 3
                                    [payer_id] => 2
                                    [amount] => 19.0
                                    [pays] => 1
                                    [created_at] => 2014-03-10 10:17:05
                                    [updated_at] => 2014-03-10 10:17:05
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The problem is, is if I then change the user_id condition to be, say, 99999 (which doesn't exist), it still returns all the payments with the `payers` array for each being empty, when in fact it should return a completely empty result.

The 2 queries produced for the eager loading are:

```
select * from "payments" --I want to add my user_id condition to this
```

and

```
SELECT "payers".*, 
       "payer_payment"."payment_id" AS "pivot_payment_id", 
       "payer_payment"."payer_id"   AS "pivot_payer_id", 
       "payer_payment"."amount"     AS "pivot_amount", 
       "payer_payment"."pays"       AS "pivot_pays", 
       "payer_payment"."created_at" AS "pivot_created_at", 
       "payer_payment"."updated_at" AS "pivot_updated_at" 
FROM   "payers" 
       INNER JOIN "payer_payment" 
               ON "payers"."id" = "payer_payment"."payer_id" 
WHERE  "payer_payment"."payment_id" IN ( '2', '3' ) 
       AND "user_id" = '1'  --This satisfies the condition
```

Answer (score 0):

The method *with* is only used to eager load the relation, a constraint on that relation should be set up like this:

```
$payment_data = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q){
           $q->where('payers.user_id', '=', 5);
        })->get();
);
```

You can also specify a variable to use in the *where* clause:

```
$payment_data = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q) use ($foo){
           $q->where('payers.user_id', '=', $foo);
        })->get();
);
```

Comment: I don't think that's right as that just adds a subquery which is used to determine a boolean result (return all payments if we can find some payers with user ID 5). The query should join the tables and add the condition. Adding more detail above.

Comment: I've tested the query with similar models before posting and it only returns the Payment with that payers condition.

Comment: I tested it on my models and it returns an empty result. See edit above

Comment: What about this: 
    Payment::with('payers')
       ->join('payers', 'payment.id', '=', 'payers.id')
       ->where('payers.user_id','=',5)
       ->get()

Comment: Ok I checked the edit question, at least you will get the idea of how to use a join clause in a related model to adjust it to your model.

Comment: Actually I think your original method is close, but I need to combine it with eager loading as I want the pivot fields too. So I tried `$payment_data = Payment::with('payers')->whereHas('payers', function($q){$q->where('user_id', '=', 1);})->get();` but I get an empty result like before. Any ideas why?

Comment: Also, the reason your first answer didn't work for me is that there is a problem with the sqlite parameter bindings in laravel and the id was being bound as a string thus returning an empty result: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3435

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it the other way around

```
User::find(5)->with('payers.payments')->get();
```

You will have a class with your payers and their payments so to get them all you need to loop them, I think joins can do this job perfectly since you don't need to loop.

Comment: this seems to do some sort of infinite loop

Comment: Oops forgot to add the get() method at the end.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after extensive searching, and a [problem with eloquent + sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303497/laravel-sqlite-wherehas-queries-not-working) I have the answer:

You need to first get only the payments for the required user using `whereHas`:

```
$payments = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id); 
},'>=', DB::raw('1'))->get();
```

Then, rather than call the eager loading on the entire `Payment` model, you just call it on your payment collection you just made (lazy eager loading):

```
$payment_data = $payments->load(array(
    'payers' => function($q){
       $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
}));
```

This adds the pivot data to your $payments collection giving you what you need without querying every payment in the database which is what the first method in the question does.