# Laravel SQLite whereHas queries not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm using SQLite with my Laravel app and trying to run a `whereHas` query:

```
$payments = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', '=', 1); 
})->get();
```

This returns an empty result and is due to the integer 1 being cast to a string as evidenced by the resulting query generated by laravel/eloquent:

```
select * from "payments" where (select count(*) from "payers" inner join "payer_payment" on "payers"."id" = "payer_payment"."payer_id" where "payer_payment"."payment_id" = "payments"."id" and "user_id" = 1) >= '1'
```

Having reviewed [this github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3353) I tried using `DB::raw` like so:

```
$payments = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q){
      $q->where('user_id', '=', DB::raw(1)); 
})->get();
```

But no improvement. How can I fix this without changing database driver?

Answer (score 0):

```
$payments = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q){
      $q->where('user_id', '=', 1); 
}, '>=', DB::raw(1))->get();
```